# Can I carry alcohol for personal use in Rishikesh

Tags: india, alcohol

I reached Rishikesh today and I am bit reluctant to ask anyone if I can bring in a bottle of whiskey from nearby area to Rishikesh for personal consumption at my apartment, is it even legal ?, I know Rishikesh is a holy place but it's still a town where people live and like to drink occasionally, I couldn't find any official orders to refer to

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_laws_of_India), there are no restriction on alcohol use (except for minimum age) in the state of Uttarakhand.

Obviously, public drinking and drunkenness is probably frown upon (or will get you cited for public disturbance) and bringing alcohol in a holy place it surely not a good idea (this applies to most religions holy places)

I think that if you have your own alcohol and drink it in private and don't get drunk, you should be OK.

Comment: thanks for the response but in India things on paper are far different from the things in reality, I did some digging although what you are saying is correct if police search you and find alcohol they may harass you but it's very unlikely that they may check but I couldn't risk it but locals are really helpful security guard introduced me to a guy who delivers alcohol to people living in my building he charged me 200 bucks extra for a bottle which was quite reasonable and my bottle was home delivered

Comment: it's quite complicated